# Properly discontinuous actions and discrete groups in complete Riemannian manifolds.

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, topological-groups, complete-spaces

I was reading the article "The Geometries of 3-manifolds" by Peter Scott and in the end of page 406 he states the following:

> If $G$ acts properly discontinuously on a space $X$, then $G$ is a
>   discrete subset of the space of all continuous functions $X \to X$
>   with the compact-open topology. The converse is false, in general, but
>   is true if $X$ is a complete Riemannian manifold and $G$ is a group of
>   isometries of $X$.

How do I prove the last statement?

> If $X$ is a complete Riemannian manifold and
>   $G$ is a group of isometries of $X$ acting properly discontinuously on $X$, then $G$ is discrete.

Observation: We say a group $G$ of homeomorphisms of $X$ acts properly discontinuously on $X$ if for every compact $K \subset X$ the set
$$\{g \in G: gK \cap K \neq \emptyset\}$$
is finite.

Comment: Do you mean, if $G$ is a group of isometries that is discrete subset in the compact-open topology on $\operatorname{Hom}(X)$, with $X$ a complete Riemannian manifold, then $G$ acts properly discontinuously on $X$? To me, *that* is the last statement in the quote.

Comment: If $X$ is a complete Riemannian manifold, then the Hopf-Rinow theorem says that $X$ is a complete metric space, and so all the closed and bounded subsets of $X$ are compact. Can't you use that somehow?

Comment: @RyleeLyman I mean exactly that.

Comment: A form of this question was asked many times, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493767/a-problem-of-a-discrete-group-of-smooth-isometries-acting-discontinuously-on-a-s?rq=1. I am sure it was also answered at MSE. There are many ways to prove this result, for instance, using Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Why your linked post is a duplicate of this post? it is earlier than this one!!

Comment: @C.F.G: The timing is irrelevant. What is relevant is that one post contains an answer to another. Arguably, I could have answered another post and voted to close this one as a duplicate. I do not remember why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is a (complete) metric space which satisfies the Heine-Borel property (every closed and bounded subset is compact). For instance, you can take $X$ to be a complete connected (finite dimensional) Riemannian manifold equipped with Riemannian distance function.

Then Arzela-Ascoli theorem implies that for every sequence of isometries $f_i: X\to X$ such that there exists $p\in X$ and $R$ for which $d(p, f_i(p))\le R$ for all $i$, there exists a subsequence $(f_{i_j})$ which converges to an isometry uniformly on compacts in $X$.

Given this, let us prove

**Lemma.** Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of $Isom(X)$ (the isometry group of $X$) equipped with the topology of uniform convergence on compacts. Then $\Gamma$ acts properly discontinuously on $X$.

**Proof.** Suppose not. Then there exists a compact $K\subset X$ and  an infinite sequence of distinct elements $\gamma_i\in\Gamma$ such that $\gamma_i K\cap K\ne \emptyset$. Taking $p\in K$ and $R=2diam(K)$, we conclude that for each $\gamma_i$, $d(\gamma_i(p), p)\le R$. Therefore, by the above observation, $(\gamma_i)$ contains a convergent subsequence $(\gamma_{i_j})$. Taking the sequence of products 
$$
\alpha_j:= \gamma_{i_j}^{-1} \gamma_{i_{j+1}},
$$
we conclude that $\alpha_j\to id$ uniformly on compacts. (I am using here the property that $Isom(X)$ with topology of uniform convergence on compacts is a topological group.) Hence, $\Gamma$ is not a discrete subgroup of $Isom(X)$. A contradiction. qed

Comment: Cool! Thank you!

Comment: How does one see that the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem imply the existence of this subsequence?

Comment: @Dai: Isometries form an equicontinuous family. Then you verify that the limit of a convergent sequence of isometries is an isometry.

Comment: Still confused how does the property $d(p,f_i(p))<R$ play a role here?

Comment: @Dai: Yes: AA theorem in its usual form requires compactness. What you have is only compactness of images of balls. For each $r\in {\mathbb N}$ you consider $B_r=\bar{B}(p,r)$ and note that $f_i(B_r)\subset \bar{B}(p, r+R)$ and the latter is compact.  Now, you use AA theorem plus a diagonal subsequence argument to construct a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!